# Warning: #4038 Syntax error in JSON text in argument 1 to function 'st_geomfromgeojson' at position 29

Tags: mysql, geometry, polygon, latitude-longitude

I'm trying to find a point (lng, lat) in a polygon, and I have a database table called `states` as follows:

| id | name | bounds |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | state name | '{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[25.64214,-100.27873]],[[25.69505,-100.37006]],[[25.72599,-100.27702]],[[25.680978320466,-100.25384240723]]]}' |
| .. | .. | .. |
| .. | .. | .. |

My query is:

```
SELECT * FROM `states` WHERE 
ST_Contains(ST_GeomFromText(ST_asText(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(bounds))),POINT(47.785031, 30.534336))
```

> POINT and coordinates are fake, just to explain my idea.

Resulting nothing with this warning:

```
 Warning: #4038 Syntax error in JSON text in argument 1 to function 'st_geomfromgeojson' at position 29
```

What I messing? why this error occured!?

Comment: The example you posted has valid JSON, but maybe some other rows in the table don't.

Comment: You need to figure out which row is causing the error, and check its JSON. jsonlint.com should be helpful.

Comment: @Barmar I have only 5 states, and I checked them as you said but all row's bounds are a valid JSON!

Comment: Try using the option 2 argument to `ST_GeomFromGeoJSON()` because your coordinates have more than 2 dimensions. See the documentation [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-geojson-functions.html#function_st-geomfromgeojson)

Comment: @Barmar The same! nothing changed

Comment: Seems like the brackets are too nested.

Comment: After updating a column of the table from phpmyadmin, I had occurred this error too. Because the table setted the column's default value from [] to '\'[]\''. That's why it wasn't working.

Comment: @Barmar You save me!!!!!!!! after 2 years later from you posted a comment!