# mysql - Find a point (lng, lat) in a polygon stored as a string

Tags: php, mysql, sql, polygon, latitude-longitude

I'm trying to find a point (lng, lat) in a polygon, and I have a database table called `states` as follows:

| id | name | bounds |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | state name | '{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[25.64214,-100.27873]],[[25.69505,-100.37006]],[[25.72599,-100.27702]],[[25.680978320466,-100.25384240723]]]}' |
| .. | .. | .. |
| .. | .. | .. |

what I want is, return the **state name** or the whole **row** according to the given **point [lng, lat]** (e.g. user's location) by searching the **bounds**.

how can I achieve that?

Comment: Why is this stored as a string? If you want to deal with latitudes and longitudes in SQL, then store these separately in your database. And what is it you are having problems with? Extracting the values from the string? Finding an algorith to say whether a point is within a polygon? Something else? Please tell and show us how far you've got and what exactly you need help with.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Thanks for you reply, I'm trying to find a point if within the polygon or not, ex: a user gives his location (lng, lat), so I want to find his location if within a polygon of one of the states stored in the DB as above, then return the state matched.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner + I already have my query but I'm facing an issue with it as posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68688012/warning-4038-syntax-error-in-json-text-in-argument-1-to-function-st-geomfromg

Comment: It would be best to extract the polygon data from JSON and save it as one of spatial data types (e.g. POLYGON) then use MySQL spatial functions such as ST_Contains to find if input lat/lon is contained inside one of those polygons

Comment: @SalmanA can you please show me how to do that?